# Spring boot security giving 500 internal error after passing the credentials

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-security, vaadin, tomcat8

When I run a Vaadin web application in the IntelliJ with the Smart Tomcat plug-in in my local machine I get 500 internal server error from Spring Security right after entering the username and password. Could someone help do debug and find out what the issue could be?

- Spring Boot Starter Web: 2.3.1
- Spring Boot Starter Security: 2.3.1
- Waffle Spring Security: 4.1.8.2

**Security Configuration Class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Generated
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    private static final String LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL = "/login";
    private static final String LOGIN_FAILURE_URL = "/login?error";
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";
    private static final String LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL = "/";

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilter negotiateSecurityFilter;

    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint entryPoint;

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        // disable Spring CSRF here to be able to use plain
        // HTML for the login page
        http.csrf().disable();

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
            .and()
                .addFilterBefore(negotiateSecurityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        web.
            ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                "/VAADIN/**",                    // Vaadin Flow static resources
                "/favicon.ico",                  // the standard favicon URI
                "/robots.txt",                   // the robots exclusion standard
                                                 // web application manifest
                "/manifest.webmanifest", "/sw.js", "/offline-page.html",
                "/icons/**", "/images/**",       // icons and images
                "/frontend/**",                  // (development mode) static resources
                "/webjars/**",                   // (development mode) webjars
                "/h2-console/**",                // (development mode) H2 debugging console
                                                 // (production mode) static resources
                "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**");
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
    15:03:56.519 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
15:03:56.519 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
15:03:56.566 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
15:03:56.566 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 47 ms
15:03:56.638 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/VAADIN/'
15:03:56.638 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/favicon.ico'
15:03:56.638 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/robots.txt'
15:03:56.638 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/manifest.webmanifest'
15:03:56.638 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/sw.js'
15:03:56.638 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/offline-page.html'
15:03:56.638 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/icons/'
15:03:56.638 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/images/'
15:03:56.638 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/frontend/'
15:03:56.638 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/webjars/'
15:03:56.638 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/h2-console/'
15:03:56.638 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/frontend-es5/'
15:03:56.638 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/frontend-es6/'
15:03:56.644 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
15:03:56.657 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
15:03:56.663 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
15:03:56.663 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
15:03:56.683 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
15:03:56.697 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
15:03:56.697 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
15:03:56.697 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
15:03:56.697 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
15:03:56.697 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
15:03:56.697 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
15:03:56.697 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
15:03:56.697 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
15:03:56.697 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
15:03:56.697 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found
15:03:56.697 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'NegotiateSecurityFilter'
15:03:56.705 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
15:03:56.705 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
15:03:56.705 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - saved request doesn't match
15:03:56.705 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
15:03:56.719 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
15:03:56.726 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@d6afbfc3: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
15:03:56.726 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
15:03:56.726 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.SessionManagementFilter - Requested session ID 464CBD4742DDF4C08C993E77C77C2015 is invalid.
15:03:56.727 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
15:03:56.727 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
15:03:56.727 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [authenticated]
15:03:56.727 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@d6afbfc3: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
15:03:56.806 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@152a93ca, returned: -1
15:03:56.838 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    ...
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
...
15:03:56.946 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.NegatedRequestMatcher - matches = true
15:03:56.946 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AndRequestMatcher - All requestMatchers returned true
15:03:57.000 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8087/AutomatorUI/]
15:03:57.000 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Calling Authentication entry point.
15:03:57.001 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3b282a1a
15:03:57.001 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
15:03:57.016 [http-nio-8087-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/VAADIN/'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/favicon.ico'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/robots.txt'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/manifest.webmanifest'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/sw.js'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/offline-page.html'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/icons/'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/images/'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/frontend/'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/webjars/'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/h2-console/'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/frontend-es5/'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/frontend-es6/'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@61127d6a. A new one will be created.
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found
15:03:57.021 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'NegotiateSecurityFilter'
15:03:57.698 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3b282a1a
15:03:57.698 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
15:03:57.698 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
15:03:57.699 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] ERROR o.s.b.w.s.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [Filter execution threw an exception]
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    ....
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\q1027217\.SmartTomcat\TMFAutomator\AutomatorUI\temp\jna-1329143075\jna1563127960288887144.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1820)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:782)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1098)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:851)
    ...
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
15:03:57.727 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/AutomatorUI/error", parameters={}
: Name [spring.mvc.view.suffix] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.mvc.view.suffix].
15:03:58.070 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.mvc.view.suffix]
15:03:58.070 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.mvc.view.suffix] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.mvc.view.suffix] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.mvc.view.suffix].. Returning null.
15:03:58.124 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
15:03:58.151 [http-nio-8087-exec-3] **DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 500**
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by JDK which was failing while calling the waffle authentication framework. I had installed Java 8u361 and changed the version to Java 8u121 to make the application work. I am not sure what is different in these two build which was causing an internal exception.